# Latex not generating .aux file and .bbl file for latex2rtf

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, overleaf, latex2rtf

I am trying to convert a latex pdf using `latex2rtf`. My latex document is generated using the [ACM Conference Proceedings Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-master-template/pnrfvrrdbfwt). The `latex2rtf` instructions says that I need the .aux file and .bbl file which are generated by running latex on the `.tex` file.

[image]

So, I ran the `sample-authordraft.tex` file, but I did not get the aux and bbl file that `latex2rtf` is looking for. `sample-authordraft.bbl` and `sample-authordraft.aux` are missing. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

EDIT1: I was able to get the aux and bbl files from overleaf, still could not find through local run. However, I am still getting the following errors:

```
sample-authordraft.tex:1   Document format <acmart> unknown, using article format
sample-authordraft.tex:1   Package/option 'sigconf' unknown.
sample-authordraft.tex:1   Package/option 'authordraft' unknown.
sample-authordraft.tex:2   Package/option 'siunitx' unknown.
```

Comment: If you compiled on Overleaf, you can download the .aux and .bbl files from the list of output files: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files If you're compiling locally on your own PC, these files will be available in the directory you compiled within. Note that Overleaf's output files will be named `output.aux` and `output.bbl` but you'll have to rename them to have the same base name as your main .tex file in order for `latex2rtf` to find them.

Comment: I was running the latex using GUI (pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex), and could not see any generated aux and bbl file in the directory where i was running it from. However, I was able to download it from overeaf, Thank you so much @PaulGessler

Comment: why is not able to detect the documentclass `acmart` although it is sitting in that directory as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPuX6.png

Comment: Looks like `latex2rtf` is not capable to use external classes. crap!